# How to know if max.poll.interval.ms is reached in java kafka application client?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there an exception thrown somewhere when kafka `max.poll.interval.ms` is reached and rebalance happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your consumer gets kicked out of the consumer group due to long `poll()`, you will receive a `CommitFailedException`. According to the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> It is also possible that the consumer could encounter a "livelock"
>   situation where it is continuing to send heartbeats, but no progress
>   is being made. To prevent the consumer from holding onto its
>   partitions indefinitely in this case, we provide a liveness detection
>   mechanism using the `max.poll.interval.ms` setting. Basically if you
>   don't call poll at least as frequently as the configured max interval,
>   then the client will proactively leave the group so that another
>   consumer can take over its partitions. When this happens, you may see
>   an offset commit failure (as indicated by a `CommitFailedException`
>   thrown from a call to `commitSync()`). This is a safety mechanism which
>   guarantees that only active members of the group are able to commit
>   offsets. So to stay in the group, you must continue to call poll.

---

Therefore, you could possibly catch `CommitFailedException`. Actually, you can keep calling `poll()` until re-balancing is complete and your consumer re-enters the consumer group.

Comment: You will probably get an exception in your heartbeat thread much earlier, something along the lines "Heartbeat thread failed due to unexpected error: ..."

Comment: @mazaneicha I'd say it depends on the configuration.

Comment: I think, regardless. If a consumer has been kicked out from the group but continues to send heartbeats, it will get an exception. A reprimand for not polling :)

Comment: @mazaneicha What if say both `heartbeat.interval.ms` and `session.timeout.ms` are fairly large? I mean that `CommitFailedException` would preced.

Comment: That'd be a real shame :) because heartbeats are also used to communicate group rebalancings back to consumers. But you're right, theoretically its feasible.

Comment: @mazaneicha Agreed. But theoretically, it is possible.